# JAVA Inner class Variable access

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, java-me, android-volley

I have class with static method and in which I called JsonObjectRequest constructor and overrided the onResponse method. Once i get response in onResponse method  i want to return TRUE or else false. Please help me how to pass Boolean value from method.

public class DeviceInfo{

```
public static Boolean deviceInformation()
{

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {
                        // Parsing json object response
                        // response will be a json object
                        String name = response.getString("name");
                        String email = response.getString("email");
                        JSONObject phone = response.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");

                        jsonResponse = "";
                        jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n";

                        txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // hide the progress dialog
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);



return Boolean;
}

}
```

Comment: I am not sure it is entirely clear what you are asking. It is customary to use the question to explain the problem in more detail, rather than just relying on the title.

Comment: Hello Halfer.. Sorry for unclear question.. I have class with static method and in which I called  JsonObjectRequest constructor and implemneted onResponse method. Once i get response i want to return TRUE or else false

Comment: OK, would you add that into the question, by editing it please?

Comment: (Aside: your method `deviceInforamtion` is misspelled, by the way).

Comment: Thats not possible since your request is asynchronous, thats the whole point of having the onResponse callback.  Once the request is created  and added to the queue the function will complete on its thread while the request is completed on another. You'll need to restructure your logic for whatever you're trying to achieve. If you want help with that edit and expand your question.

Comment: I can Implement Listener and update it right ??